# Clarification regarding comments within any statement

Tags: c++

When I am *commenting* within any statement like:

```
   std::cout/*inside cout statement*/<<"Howdy"<<endl;  //Code 1
```

or

```
 std::cout/*inside cout 
 statement*/<<"Howdy"<<endl;    //Code 2
```

it is working perfectly fine (especially amazed by working of the **code 2** in which that entire thing is broken into two lines -The only problem occurs when some token is **broken** internally like:

```
  c/*the hell*/out<<"Howdy"<<endl;  //cout is broken
```

How exactly is compiler dealing with this?

Comment: It's not dealing with it. Your code is ill-formed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `/* ... */` comment is removed and replaced with a single space in the next phase of processing.

So the first two examples are equivalent to:

```
cout << "Howdy" << endl;
```

But the last example is treated as if you'd written:

```
c out << "Howdy" << endl;
```

which is obviously invalid because of the space inside `c out`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks reasonable but what is going on in the code 2, it doesn't seem that replacing comment with space should work there.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work there? A space is allowed between `cout` and `<<`.

Comment: o, I was thinking in wrong direction as the comment was spread over more than one line.

Comment: You know that statements can be spread over multiple lines, don't you? You can have `cout` on one line and `<<` on the next.

Comment: @Gaurav: Specifically, the C++ compiler ignores newlines almost entirely.

Comment: More specifially, newlines are treated just like any other whitespace, except for the purpose of ending `//` comments.

Comment: ... Or braking lines apart with a ` \ `.

Comment: @StoryTeller The preprocessor works on lines, that's where you need to escape newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Because in preprocessor stage, removed the comments and replaced with next characters. Then compiler stage checks the syntax of the code.

Comment: If it just removed the comments it would become `cout`, which is valid syntax. The important thing is that it's replaced with a space.

Comment: The question is about `/*` comments, not `//` comments.